# How can I fix the NoSuchMethodError while using the open-rewrite plugin for migrating Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.7.x?

Tags: openrewrite

Error while trying to migrate srping boot 1.5.x to 2.7.x using open-rewrite

Using this plugin

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.44.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <activeRecipes>
            <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot2.UpgradeSpringBoot_2_7</recipe>
          </activeRecipes>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.34.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

As mentioned in docs https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/popular-recipe-guides/spring-boot-2.x-migration-from-spring-boot-1.x

Getting this error

```
Execution default-cli of goal org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:4.44.0:dryRun failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openrewrite.java.search.UsesType.<init>(java.lang.String)'
```

Trying to run mvn rewrite:run as mentioned in docs

Comment: There are newer version of both the plugin as well the recipe 4.46.0 and 4.36.0 respectivelily.

Comment: Indeed; using the latest version should resolved this issue. Thanks @M.Deinum!

Comment: Also working on updating the docs, as it's not your fault when looking at the current documentation: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-docs/pull/171

Answer (score 0):

The documentation was slightly outdated; which I've [fixed just now](https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-docs/pull/171). If you [reopen the docs](https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/popular-recipe-guides/spring-boot-2.x-migration-from-spring-boot-1.x) you'll see an updated code snippet suggesting you instead use:

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.46.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <activeRecipes>
            <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot2.UpgradeSpringBoot_2_7</recipe>
          </activeRecipes>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.36.0</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

Hope that helps!